# async/await version of the promise callback waterfall issue

Tags: javascript, async-await

it seems that if i have a nested function with an async call, every parent function has to be defined as an async function. this just doesn't seem right; am i missing something?

in the example below, the console will print out: c, b, a, d
i need the d() to complete before c() finishes ... in other words, the result needs to be d, c, b, a

if i attempt to fix this by adding async/await to c(), it merely moves the problem up one function.

```
const fakeAsyncFn = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // emulate async call
    }, 100);
};

const a = () => {
    b();
    console.log('a');
};

const b = () => {
    c();
    console.log('b');
};

const c = async () => {
    d();
    console.log('c');
};

const d = async () => {
    const result = await fakeAsyncFn();
    // do something with result
    console.log('d');
};

console: c, b, a, d
```

is a complete code re-organization necessary to make this happen? or am i just completely baffled as to how async/await works?

thanks for your time!
bill

Comment: Nope, that's correct! You need to make all parent functions `async`. At least that worked for me.

Comment: If every function in the stack needs the result of the async function or needs it to complete before continuing on, then yes they all would have to become async. You cannot return to sync code from async code

Comment: It's async all the way down. It must be if you want each function to work with the sync data of the async function it calls. That's...what async really means - once one piece of data is coming *later* you cannot really work as if it's here *now*. The data that depends on the *later* data will also come *later*. And so on and so forth.

Comment: thanks Petyor, Patrick and VLAZ, at least i can stop looking for work arounds and make sure the code is structured appropriately!


"It's async all the way down."  sorta like the turtles.  : )